# Issue with passing data for registration in redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, redux-saga

I have a problem inside redux-saga workflow in registering a single user. This is part of the code for redux-saga:

```
// Relative imports
import * as ActionTypes from "./constants";
import { signupAPI } from "../../../utils/webAPI";

function* signup(action) {
    try {
      yield call(signupAPI, action.data);
      yield put({ type: ActionTypes.USER_SIGNUP_SUCCESS });
    } catch (error) {
      yield put({ type: ActionTypes.USER_SIGNUP_ERROR, error });
    }
  }

export default [takeLatest(ActionTypes.USER_SIGNUP_REQUESTING, signup)];
```

This one is an API call to server:

```
// POST request to create user with email, password, firstName, lastName
export const signupAPI = data => http.post(`${API}/users`, data);
```

I am using axios and "http" is a configuration of axios.
What I want to do: pass data of email, password, name, last name in signupAPI. What I get is this: [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUx1S.png)
I am not sure what is done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Error in reducer file which was founding unused variable.